# Как автоматически построить визуальное отображение взаимодействия между формами?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Есть Windows Forms приложение в котором много форма.
Одна форма вызывает другую форму, другая форма передает данные следующей форме и все в таком духе.

Есть ли какие-нибудь инструменты, которые могут автоматически построить какую-нибудь диаграмму взаимодействия между формами по коду проекта?

Comment: Автоматических не встречал, а что мешает самому сделать? Берём команду вызова формы, парсим код проекта и визуализируем как удобнее.